# Heroku - Python simple POST api, only can do GET (cannot do POST)

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I want to do a web API which consist only POST. Currently I need to run python script on the web, so I am building a python web server from flask in Heroku. However, my issue is, whenever I send POST request from POSTMAN, what I will receive is the return data which is actually from GET request. Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def api_grab_key():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
            return request.json["imgUrl"]
        else:
            return "Request must be in JSON"
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "Hello World! GET request"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

It works when I run locally, but not on Heroku. On Heroku, the output is always "Hello World! GET request" Thanks!

Comment: What does `curl -XPOST -HContent-Type:application/json -d'{"imgUrl":"test"}' localhost:33507` show?  What about `curl -XPOST -HContent-Type:application/json -d'{"imgUrl":"test"}' HEROKU_APP_ROUTE`?

Comment: It still says "GET request" after the curl and apparently my issue is in the URL i sent my request to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, apparently my issue is in the URL. So in Heroku, it has xxx.heroku.com and xxx.herokuapp.com.
I don't know why, requests sent to xxx.heroku.com turns into GET request. So, I had to change it to xxx.herokuapp.com for POST request.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything jumping out, have you tried enabling debugging mode in Flask?

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Then:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: This is a suggestion about how to debug, not an answer to the question.  Should probably ask OP to provide more debug output in comments before providing an answer.